# Screen.Bounds is not returning correct values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-framework-version

in my winform App, i wanted to get the system's resolution and using Scren.bounds for this. Code was running pretty good few weeks before and it was getting correct values but somhow for past few days it's not returning correct values and always return 560 X 300 whereas my Resolution is set to 1366 X 768 with 100% scaled!
As you can see in the attachted images in debuging values show width and height of 556 and 300 respectively where as if a see these debugging values in IEnumerbale Visualizer then it's showing correct values (1366 X 768).
Can anyone point out the issue or i'm missing something!

.net Target Framework is 4.6.2
while i'm using window 11.

[image]

[IEnumerableVisulaizer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH3cq.png)

i have tried every possible solution making app dpi Aware, setting scale to 100% etc but nothing worked for me so far!
Thanks!

Comment: "As you can see in the attachted images in debuging values show width and height of 556 and 300 respectively" - no they don't, they show 0x00000556 and 0x00000300 respectively - *hex* 556 and *hex* 300, which are 1366 and 768 respectively. The only thing wrong is your interpretation of the debugger display.

Comment: What does *Code [...] was getting correct values [...] but [now] it's not returning correct values* mean? Is this all about the values you're misinterpreting, or do you actually have some problems with the **results** you're getting? I.e., is there an actual problem that made you go back and inspect those values?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please [read the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question accordingly.

Comment: I somehow misunderstood that; the values are indeed correct and in hex format,
Thanks for Helping guys!

Comment: @ JuanR it's my first time asking a question at SO so I'm sorry if there was anything that doesn't meet the guidelines of SO. Next time I will keep this in mind and will ask my question according to the Guidelines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Size property is correct as it shows resolution in hexadecimal values, try to convert those values to integers:

```
var width = Convert.ToInt32(Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Size.Width.ToString(), 16);

var height = Convert.ToInt32(Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Size.Height.ToString(), 16);
```